# Would an ideal gas be colder at higher altitude due to gravity?

Tags: gravity, temperature, ideal-gas

Since gas molecules are affected by gravity, wouldn't that make gas molecules at higher than average elevation slower (at the top of their ballistic parabola) and thus colder than air molecules accelerating to the ground?

Comment: Atoms are crashing into each other and thermalizing over a very small length scale... the mean free path.  Take a typical atomic radius, velocity (1/2mv^2 = 3/2kT) and density (PV=nkT) and see if you can guesstimate it.

Comment: So only in high vacuum

Comment: Yeah, I think there something about how atoms are lost at the very top of the atmosphere.  (the light H an He atoms leave first.)

Comment: Imagine gravity acting on a thermally isolated tower of gas. There will be a pressure distribution with dense gas at the bottom and less dense gas at the top. We let the gas settle into thermal equilibrium, then we insert many thermally conductive horizontal walls at different heights. The pressure on each wall will be the same from below as it is from above. Now we move the column out of the gravitational field. With gravity removed there will be a differential pressure on each wall but the walls will hold the gas in place. Will there be a temperature difference across the walls? Why not?

Comment: The answer is no. This was a controversy in the 19th century. The putative effect can be referred to as the Loschmidt gravito-thermal effect.  Boltzmann, Maxwell, and Guthrie debated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since gas molecules are affected by gravity, wouldn't that make gas molecules at higher than average elevation slower (at the top of their ballistic parabola) and thus colder than air molecules accelerating to the ground?

In non-relativistic theory no, because in thermodynamic equilibrium temperature has to be the same everywhere. The slowing down does not occur on average because the molecules do not move along ballistic parabola, but collide with each other (in very rarified gas the collisions are rare and the establishment of the same temperature as down below may take long time).

In relativistic theory, yes because in thermodynamic equilibrium places with lower gravitational potential should have higher temperature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest%E2%80%93Tolman_effect); but the predicted difference is negligibly small for common gravitational fields like Earth's.

Comment: In very rarefied gas, shouldn't the molecules behave like other matter and follow a parabolic trajectory?

Comment: Yes, in between collisions. When molecules collide, they exchange energy and this process alone leads to establishment of the same temperature everywhere. In practice, the conditions of thermodynamic equilibrium are not satisfied because there are other processes changing energy of the molecules (solar and Earth radiation), so temperature of the atmosphere changes with height.

Comment: But how would you ensure thermodynamic equilibrium? A column of gas will not be in thermodynamic equilibrium unless it is enforced by an exterior heat bath I think.

Comment: @RobJeffries, the Earth would have to be enclosed in a container preventing loss of atmosphere particles and to block incoming solar radiation and outgoing Earth radiation. Of course, as of now, the Earth is not in thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: But that is my point. It is not possible for an isolated column of gas to achieve thermodynamic equilibrium in a gravitational field.

Comment: Why not, if it is isolated?

Comment: The equilibrium is achieved via molecular collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. In the atmosphere, pressure and density fall with altitude. So does temperature. It's all to do with the trade off between thermal and potential energy. Hence lapse rate $=\frac{\text{gravity}}{ \text{specific heat capacity}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, no.

Unless energy is trying to pass through the gas.

Then, yes.

If there is no energy input/output from the gas: "energy" may be transferred from top-down, but since a density gradient also forms, that energy is shared among more molecules. Net result is that the energy per molecule becomes roughly uniform and we have a uniform "temperature".

If energy is passing through the gas, under the influence of pressure/gravity, the gas forms convection cycles which quickly form a lapse rate (= -g K/km).

Note: The fact that lapse rate = g, tells us that convection is the main heat transfer mechanism in the atmosphere. Radiative transfer is a negligible component.

A.

Comment: How do you reconcile this with the requiremnet of $PV^{\gamma}=$constant for an adiabatically isolated gas?